# css and js not loading in magento2

Tags: javascript, css, cache, indexing, magento-2.1.9

In my case css and js files are not loading. It shows only html content both front end and backend part.

I applied many times clear the cache and reindexing.

Also run these commands:

```
1.sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

2.php bin/magento setup:di:compile

3.php bin/magento indexer:reindex

4.sudo chmod -R 777 var/*
```

Delete Some folder under Pub/Static Directory:

```
MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/_requirejs

MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/adminhtml

MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static/frontend
```

Comment: @BenCrook,I already followed above step which are mentioned is previous link.but it seems not fixed.

Comment: @Ranganathan.S, css and js file show correct path from as per my custom theme directory.

Comment: how to import css and js please provide your code

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala. actually. it not occurs issue with path of css and js directory. admin pannel also same issue. after installation few extension than this type of problem occurs now.

Comment: but which types of problem occurs now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed.After replace .htacess file on root directory.
It worked like charm...:)